# Unable to customize labels and legend in Seaborn python

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="darkgrid")


df  = pd.read_csv('Leap_Static_trials.csv')
Length = sns.swarmplot(x='name', y= 'length', data= df, color = 'green')
Width = sns.swarmplot(x='name', y= 'width', data= df, color = 'red')

plt.legend(labels=['Length','Width'])
plt.show()
```

From my dataset `df` I am plotting the length and width of the fingers taken from Leap Motion Controller. I am unable to change the legend to include the second color (red) which signifies the width.

Please find the attached figure as well. Your help is much appreciated. :)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the parameter `label=` to a plot command usually creates the legend handles and labels automatically. In this case, seaborn creates handles for each column (so 5 of each). A trick is to create the legend with only the first and the last of the handles and the labels.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="darkgrid")
N = 100
# df  = pd.read_csv('Leap_Static_trials.csv')
names = list('abcde')
ax = plt.gca()
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': np.random.choice(names, N),
                   'length': np.random.normal(50, 0.7, N),
                   'width': np.random.normal(20, 0.5, N)})
Length = sns.swarmplot(x='name', y='length', data=df, color='green', label='Length', order=names, ax=ax)
Width = sns.swarmplot(x='name', y='width', data=df, color='red', label='Width', ax=ax)

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend([handles[0], handles[-1]], [labels[0], labels[-1]])
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]